# Detect link with no href

Tags: preg-match

```
$string='<dt class="comment-author " id="c6290261621627103206">
  <a name="c6290261621627103206"></a>
  <a href="http://www.google.com">bob</a>
  said...
  </dt>';
```

I want to be able to detect if a  tag is missing the href. I have tried:

```
\<a(?!href)(.*?)\<\/a\>
```

and various preg_match variations on that. But sadly to no avail. I should state that I only want to detect, I do not need to output and values from the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your RegEx, your matches will be very limited.

Try this RegEx, it can find the value of a href tag on the page regardless of where it falls. If there is no value returned, there is no href tag!

```
(?<=href\=")[^]+?(?=")
```

The lookahead match of `href\="` will look for/match the href at any position instead of RIGHT AFTER the `a` only.

Comment: Yeah suppose I can just !preg_match it. Thanks. I got caught up in trying to detect adsense of href.